# Order by many to many relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеем отношение Many to Many

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, "event_parent_model");
}
```

Как сделать orderBy("events.start_at")

```
ParentModel::whereHas("events")
    ->with([
        "events" => function ($query) {
            $query->latest("start_at")->limit(4);
        },
        "events.address"
    ]);
```

Comment: `$query->orderBy('start_at', 'desc')->limit(4);` - так не работает разве?

Comment: @РустамГимранов ну так сортируются events а мне надо отсортировать ParentModel и потом использовать пагинацию